# Trouble installing Qemu using apt-get

Tags: apt, permissions, dpkg

I am pretty much brand new to Ubuntu, and I need it for a CS class I am taking.

I am trying to install Qemu, a PC emulator.  I found directions that say

`apt-get install qemu`

should get everything going, but when I try this I get the following error message:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg), are you root?
```

Not sure how to fix this, would greatly appreciate any help.

I tried doing an `ls -l`  to view permissions on lock, I see the following:

`-rw-r-----`

Not sure if that helps.

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: apt-get needs sudo to work (administrator privileges). Just add it to the command: sudo apt-get install qemu

Comment: @darent  Bam. Works like a champ. Much appreciation, would give you a +1 but not sure how to on comments...

Comment: Nevermind the points, Im glad it helped. You should mark Ravan's answer as solved so other people with a similar problem can find it easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sudo` to run a command with root privileges:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu
```

Reference:  [UsingTheTerminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)

Comment: `As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid][askubuntu.com/help](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer))! **;-)**